# Oracle connection issues from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ssis-2008

Getting connection error on oledb source from the SSIS package  to import the data from oracle to sql server. It is failing after deploying to server but runs fine when being run from BIDS from local machine. The package is developed in 2008.

Is there any installation needed on server for oracle?

The following error is being displayed

> Source: Connection manager  Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider
>   MSDAORA.1 is not registered -- perhaps no 64-bit provider is
>   available.  Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154 
>   Description: "Class not registered".   Code: 0xC020801C     OLE DB
>   Source [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager failed with
>   error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>   Code: 0xC0047017     Source:  SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component
>   "OLE DB Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code
>   0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2019-06-18 22:54:18.99     Code:
>   0xC004700C     Source: Pipeline     Description: One or more component
>   failed validation.

When I am validating the package, there it is giving ORA-01017: invalid username/password; but the same credentials are used while running from local machine.

I am running it in 32 bit but still the error persists
Also tried with ProtectionLevel as Dontsavesensitive but no luck

Comment: If you get an `ORA-01017` then installation of OLE DB provider is fine, otherwise you would not get any error from Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install an Oracle client. The bare Instant Client should be sufficient as you use the [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) `MSDAORA` OLE DB provider from Microsoft.

If you like to use the Oracle Provider for OLE DB (`OraOLEDB.Oracle`) then you must install the provider. It is not included in the Instant Client.

Ensure that the architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) is the same as your application. Your question is not clear in that. You write "I am running it in 32 bit" but the error message "The requested OLE DB provider MSDAORA.1 is not registered -- perhaps no 64-bit provider is available." indicates 64-bit.

Note, old `MSDAORA` provider from Microsoft exist only for 32-bit. If you need a 64-bit version then you must take the provider from Oracle.

32-bit drivers can be downloaded from [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html), the 64-bit drives are available at [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you elaborate more on Oracle Provider for OLE DB (OraOLEDB.Oracle) which is not included in the Instant Client. What is needed for this? and will it be supported from SSIS 2008? Regarding the 32 bit ot 64 bit, I was checking on few posts and there it was suggested that that option may solve the problem. so I had disabled that Runas64 bit Option

Comment: Provider "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" needs to be installed. You will find the downloads in the links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle drivers on the production machine. If I remember one way to do it is to install the x64 Oracle client software for Windows. Its enormous but it seems to work. This has worked for me.

According to this stackoverflow answer you can manually install the drivers but its a lot of steps:

https://serverfault.com/questions/175257/how-to-install-oracle-ole-drivers-for-use-in-sql-server-2008-r2-x64

Comment: I suggest this driver - it''s much tinier: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html. Can't comment on performance though. Obviously it needs to match whatever is used in the SSIS package